# Can we seal the bedroom door gap, or will it affect the central air conditioning airflow?

Tags: sound-proofing

I am trying to add some sound proofing to my baby's room. In Canada, almost all interior doors have a gap at the bottom. I believe this is for the airflow of the central furnace/air conditioner. Since the baby room only has a vent out, is there any effect on the central air airflow when I seal the gap at bottom of the door?

Just thinking if I seal it, that will mean the room will have a hard time getting air out when the furnace/air conditioner is running.

Comment: An off-topic thought for your consideration: While absolute silence may make it easier for baby to sleep _now_. In the future it will be very inconvenient for _you_ when you want the little fella to nap someplace where that level of silence cannot be maintained. The sooner she learns to sleep with some background noises and how to settle herself when she's awakened before nap time is over, the easier _both_ of your lives will be. Source: parent of 3 kids.

Comment: I do agree my wife used to vacuum while the kids slept, our oldest daughter tried the quiet thing and has regretted it until she moved out our great grand son is being raised with music in the front room so maybe it needs to skip a generation to work LOL. +

Comment: Thanks guys. Really helpful tips for new parents. I will try to keep the noise level as normal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The gap at the door allows the heated air in because if the gap is sealed once the room Is pressurized No more air can get in so the room will not heat or cool if the airspace is blocked off.